# Code First Fluent API - Rename AutoGenerated ForeignKeyID Db Column That Is Not In The Model

Tags: ef-code-first

I've followed a tutorial for Code First TPT Inheritance:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx

The User model contains a uni-directional navigation to BillingDetail. CodeFirst names the column "BillingDetail_BillingDetailId"  I would like to rename the column "BillingDetailId"
using the Fluent API.   How is this done?  Here is the User model.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual BillingDetail BillingDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to a BillingDetailId property on the User object and then via the fluent API you can

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>()
         .Property(u => u.BillingDetailId)
         .HasColumnName("BillingDetailId ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because You have "BillingDetail " as an Attributes...what ever you extract from this Attribute will have the ColumnName of "BillingDetailId"

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
     builder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.BillingDetail).HasColumnName("BillingDetailId");
}
```